# Python Mysql insert mass assignment

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a way to mass assign in python mysql?

I have all this data:

```
uniqueId     = user_profile[1]
userName     = user_profile[2]
email        = user_profile[3]
password     = user_profile[4]
salt         = user_profile[5]
firstName    = user_profile[6]
middleName   = user_profile[7]
lastName     = user_profile[8]
gender       = user_profile[9]
birthDate    = user_profile[10]
counter      = user_profile[11]
avatarId     = user_profile[12]
coverPhoto   = user_profile[13]
status       = user_profile[14]
welcome      = user_profile[15]
joinDate     = user_profile[16]
notification = user_profile[17]
```

and manually inserting

```
insert = """INSERT INTO table (uniqueId.....) into (%d.....)""" % (uniqueId.....)
........execute
........commit
```

would be a lot of coding and I also need to do this for a lot of tables.
or is there a way to build insert?

Comment: Why bother to assign individual variables, rather than just passing `user_profile` to the insert statement?

Comment: Why use string interpolation, which exposes your code to SQL errors and exploits?

Comment: This is a personal script though. only I will be using this for migrations. @DanielRoseman so I can pass it directly?